# Update a Referenced Node with a value from the node referencing it

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

In Drupal 7, it was easy to update a referenced node with a value from the node referencing it, using rules: https://www.drupal.org/node/1836240

But how could I do the same in Drupal 8? This code is for updating a node programmatically:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
$node = Node::load($nid);
$node->setTitle('MY NEW TITLE'); // This is a special meta field
$node->set('FIELD_NAME', 'THIS IS DATA'); // This is a Field added in to the content type
$node->save();
```

What hook should I call and place this code inside? I need when the user creates a new node or updates an existing node, then a field from the referenced node been updated with the value of a field from the current node. Should I use a form alter function? Is it possible with hook form alter to update, not only the current node, but also a field from the referenced node, or is there another hook for that?

Comment: You don't need rules for this, because D8 has CRUD events for entities: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_crud/8.4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both @GiorgosK and @4k4, for pointing me to the right direction! Here is the solution:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;


function my_module_entity_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface
$entity) {
 if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() ==  'iamoriginal') {
   if (!$entity->field_my_reference->isEmpty() &&   !$entity->field_number->isEmpty() &&
 !$entity->field_hide_me->value) {
  _my_module_update_parent($entity, 'add');
 }
 }
}


function my_module_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
 if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'iamoriginal') {
$original = $entity->original;
if (!$entity->field_my_reference->isEmpty() && !$entity->field_number->isEmpty() &&
  $entity->field_hide_me->value != $original->field_hide_me->value) {
  $operation = ($entity->field_hide_me->value) ? 'sub' : 'add';
  _my_module_update_parent($entity, $operation);
}
 }
}

function _my_module_update_parent($entity, $operation) {
 $ref = $entity->get('field_my_reference')
   ->first()
   ->get('entity')
   ->getTarget()
  ->getValue();
 if ($ref->hasField('field_number_of_originals') &&        $ref->hasField('field_total_value')) {
$total = $ref->field_total_value->value;
$count = $ref->field_number_of_originals->value;
$number = $entity->field_number->value;
switch ($operation) {
  case 'add':
    $total += $number;
    $count++;
    break;
  case 'sub':
    $total -= $number;
    $count--;
    break;
}
$ref->set('field_total_value', $total);
$ref->set('field_number_of_originals', $count);
$ref->save();
 }
 }
```

If a user adds a new node of the post type "iamoriginal" then the value of the field_number is added to the refrenced node's field_total_value and +1 to the field_number_of_originals. If he later wants to disable the original node ,he gives a value to the field_hide_me and the previously added values to the referenced node are abstracted. Thank you again for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would take the route of not duplicating content and only deal with views configuration and theming instead.

This is how I would display such a field

**using views**

1. add relationship to the entity reference field
2. add field of the entity field (based on relationship)

**using a node view/display** add in your theme's `node.html.twig` code similar to this based on your actual entity reference

```
// get author's gender field value 
{{ node.uid.entity.field_gender.value }}

// get category name
{{ node.field_category.entity.name.value }}
```

### NOTES:

If this Drupal 7 module [field_extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_extractor) gets ported to D8 then it will make field integration a configurable option and you will not have to mess with twig files as it gives a entity reference field formatter that can extract any field

Alternatives that probably require more work

- creating your own module (as per poster's request) using this as a start

  ```
  use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
  //get control when entity saved or updated 
  function MODULENAME_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
    //see if its of specific type 
    if ($entity->bundle() == 'article') {

      //get values
      $title = $entity->getTitle();
      $nid = $entity->id();
      $cat = $entity->field_category[0]->entity->label();

      //set values
      $entity->field_teaser->value = 'teaser text';  
      $entity->setTitle($entity->get('field_date')->value);

      //no need to save anything its autosaved
    }
  }
  ```
- create rules with  `React on event: updating a node`

Comment: Thank you Giorgos, I know I can do that and show a field from another node but it is not what I need actually. I am trying to make a calculation and add the value of the current node to the value of a field of the refrenced node. That's why I need to update the referenced node's field. Do you know what function I need to to use to make that when a user is submiting a form? I need both nodes been updated the same time. Is that possible?

Comment: @Ioannis it was not apparent from your question, I edited  answer,  how is this for a start ?  If you want more detail you have to make your post more detailed.